# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/tft-projectBack/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I keep getting this error when trying to start up production on my full stack website

Im linking heroku and github together

I believe I'm getting this error because it can't find the index.html file in which is under my frontEnd folder.

```
promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2022-01-05T20:33:16.359847+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/tft-projectBack/client/build/index.html'
2022-01-05T20:33:16.360843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hidefromteamo.herokuapp.com request_id=230a6526-baf1-4c8d-ba38-73bf75df990f fwd="67.182.175.103" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2022-01-05T21:06:54.348554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-01-05T21:06:54.414417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-01-05T21:06:55.868312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-05T21:06:56.764062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

I have this piece of code in my server.js file and not sure if i've done it right:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Exprees will serve up production assets
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  
    // Express serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize route
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
  }
```

React and server folder are all under one root folder

[image: How my full stack folder looks like]